# javascript object that keep accurate score in a ten-pin bowling match for a single player

Tags: javascript

recently I got a job interview for a web developer position.

They ask me to create a javascript object that keep accurate score in
a ten-pin bowling match for a single player.

I have accomplished my test.

You can run the script at this url http://jsbin.com/arele5,

If you want to edit just go to this link http://jsbin.com/arele5/edit

I have two questions:

1) The javascript object works on google chrome but jsbin complains about the following construction

`var bowlingGame = new function(){...};`

If I correct the construction in the following way

`var bowlingGame = function(){...};`

the jsbin says to me that all things are ok, but it doesn't work in google chrome. Any ideas?

2) I didn't pass the job interview, indeed I didn't receive any response; so my second question is:

what would be the best way to solve the exercise?

Thanks,

Antonio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, try:

```
var bowlingGame = new (function(){ ...})();
```

As for #2, I can't exactly say why you didn't get a job, but the spacing of your code, if nothing else, isn't very pretty to look at.  I just wrote this, it's much more compact and easy to read:

```
function game(){
    this.balls = [];
}

game.prototype = {
    addBalls : function(n){
        this.balls.push.apply(this.balls, arguments);
    },

    getScoreArray : function(){
        var score=0, ball=0, frame=1, frames=[], cur;
        for(var i=0, l=this.balls.length; i<l; i++){
            score += (cur = this.balls[i])
                + ((!ball && frame<10 && cur==10 && this.balls[i+2]) || 0)
                + (frame<10 && (((ball ? this.balls[i-1] : 0) + cur) == 10) ? this.balls[i+1] || 0 : 0);
            ball = ball || (cur==10) ? 0 : 1;
            ball || (frame<10 ? frames.push(score) && frame++ : frames[9] = score);
        }

        return frames;
    }
};
```

If nothing else, run your code through something like: http://jsbeautifier.org/ if you can't keep indentation clean...